# What does this quote about meat and milk mean?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, meat-and-milk

I'm trying to understand the meaning of this quote from טעמי המצוות by מנחם בן משה הבבלי, Mitzva Lo Ta'ase 56: (I think I understand all of the words, and I'm just not able to string them together, but that could be wrong since my Hebrew's not great)

> שלא לאכול בשר בחלב שנאמר לא תבשל גדי בחלב אמו: טעם מצוה זו לאסור בהנאה ולאסור בבישול ולאסור באכילה מדלא קאמר לא תאכל בשר בחלב דמשמע בכליון חרוץ: ואמר לא תבשל שעדיין נשאר צורתו וטוב מות שמאל דוחה וימין מקרבת אמר שמ"מ אל תכלהו משהו עם הרחמים שהבשר (דין) (ולהכי הזכיר גדי אע"פ שכלם במשמע:) והחלב רחמים תדע דחדוש הוא שחידשה תורה לאסור אפילו שלא בדרך הנאתו בישול גדי בחלב אמו

This is the best I can do at translating it

> [The mitzva] of not eating meat and milk, as it says "Do not cook a kid in its mother's milk":
> The reason [?] for this mitzva is to prohibit enjoyment, cooking, and eating [of meat and milk, which can be learned from the fact] that it doesn't say "Do not eat meat and milk" which would mean diligent [maybe complete?] destruction.
> Rather it says "Do not cook", [implying] that its form remains intact. And death is better to have the left hand push away and the right hand bring closer [meaning, mercy is or should be stronger than cold, exact jedgement, though I'm not sure what the death part means]. Even so, it says do not destroy it [or maybe, do not include it?] something with mercy, because the meat (is [signifies] judgement) (and this is why it mentions a kid, even though it means all meat),
> and the milk is [signifies] mercy. Know that [this is true because] it is a Chidush that the Torah prohibited the cooking of milk and meat, even without enjoyment.

Can someone translate this better and/or explain the  meaning please? Especially the part talking about mercy and judgement.

https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990020065170205171/NLI

This is the best online version I could find, for anyone who wants to check out the original.

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand about it? Do you not read any Hebrew, or are there specific words that are difficult in this text, or do you understand all the individual words but not know how to punctuate the text, or do you know all that but have some more specific question about it? Please [edit] to clarify; meanwhile, I've closed it to answerers so you don't get answers that don't address your concern.

Comment: (a more content-descriptive title would probably also help)

Comment: Do you just want a basic translation?

Comment: Google translate might allow some idea, though the machine translate does mess up. As an example גדי gets translated as Capricorn rather than kid and מדלא קאמר gets transliterated because it is Aramaic rather than *not to say*.